# Not receiving azure-iothub message sent from the azure-event-hubs onMessage function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have a web API which can receive and send messages to a Raspberry Pi. The connection is working fine using azure-event-hubs on the web API to receive messages and azure-iothub to send messages to the raspberry.

The issue I'm having is when I try to send a message in the onMessage function (so whenever I receive a message in the webapi), the device doesn't receive it. Here is my code:

WebApi:

```
const { EventHubClient, EventPosition } = require('azure-event-hubs');
var connectionString = 'myConnectionString'
var sendingClient = require('../azure/sendingClient')

async function main() {
    sendingClient.sendMessage('raspberry',{},"allDevices")  //The raspberry receives this  
    const client = await 
    EventHubClient.createFromIotHubConnectionString(connectionString);

    const onError = (err) => {
        console.log("An error occurred on the receiver ", err);
    };

    const onMessage = (msg) => {
        console.log(msg.body);
        sendingClient.sendMessage('raspberry',{},"allDevices")// the raspberry doesn't receive this
    };

    const receiveHandler = client.receive("1", onMessage, onError, { 
        eventPosition: EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Date.now()) 
    });

  // To stop receiving events later on...
  await receiveHandler.stop();
  await client.close();
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Sending client:

```
var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-common').Message;

var connectionString = 'myConnectionString'

var sendingClient = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

exports.sendMessage = (targetDevice, content, messageId) => {
    sendingClient.open(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Service client connected');
            var message = new Message(content);
            message.ack = 'full';
            message.messageId = 'message'
            message.properties.add('message',messageId)
            console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
            console.log('Sending message to : ' + targetDevice);            
            sendingClient.send(targetDevice, message,);
        }
    });
}
```

Receiver on the raspberryPi:

```
var iothub = require('azure-iothub');
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol)
client.open((err) => {
    if (err) console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message)
    else {
        client.on('message', (msg) => {
            switch (msg.properties.propertyList[1].value) {
                case 'allDevices':
                    devices = JSON.parse(msg.data.toString())
                    response(devices) //passing the message content
            }
        });

        client.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err.message);
        });

        client.on('disconnect', () => {
            clearInterval(sendInterval);
            client.removeAllListeners();
            client.open(connectCallback);
        });
    }
})
```

sender on the RaspberryPi:

```
exports.sendMessage = (data, connectionString, key) => {
    var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol)
    client.open((err) => {
        if (err) console.error('Send message error: ' + err.message)
        else {
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
            var message = new Message(data);
            message.properties.add('message', key);
            client.sendEvent(message);
            console.log('Message sent ' + key);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the event hub client can not receive the messages form partition "1". There is no way to send a message to a specific partition in IoT Hub,Partitions are used internally to allow scaling of the IoT (Event Hub) and allow for scaling out the consumer app. You can try with following code to receive messages from all partition.

```
  const partitionIds = await client.getPartitionIds();
  partitionIds.forEach(function(id,index){
    const receiveHandler = client.receive(id, onMessage, onError, { eventPosition: EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Date.now()) });  
  });
```

**Update:**

***WebApi.js***

```
const { EventHubClient, EventPosition } = require('azure-event-hubs');
var connectionString = '{iot-hub-connectionstring}';
var sendingClient = require('./sendingClient');

async function main() {
    sendingClient.sendMessage('raspberry',{},"raspberry-first")  //The raspberry receives this  
    const client = await EventHubClient.createFromIotHubConnectionString(connectionString);

    const onError = (err) => {
        console.log("An error occurred on the receiver ", err);
    };

    const onMessage = (msg) => {
        console.log("receive response");
        console.log(msg.body);
        sendingClient.sendMessage('raspberry',{},"raspberry-second")// the raspberry doesn't receive this
    };

    const partitionIds = await client.getPartitionIds();
    partitionIds.forEach(function(id,index){
        const receiveHandler = client.receive(id, onMessage, onError, { eventPosition: EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Date.now()) });  
    });  
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

***sendingClient.js***

```
var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-common').Message;

var connectionString = '{iot-hub-connectionstring}';

var sendingClient = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

exports.sendMessage = (targetDevice, content, messageId) => {
    sendingClient.open(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log('Service client connected');
            var message = new Message(content);
            message.ack = 'full';
            message.messageId = 'message'
            message.properties.add('message',messageId)
            console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
            console.log('Sending message to : ' + targetDevice);            
            sendingClient.send(targetDevice, message,);
        }
    });
}
```

***Receiver.js***
    var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
    var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
    var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

```
var connectionString = "{iot-hub-device-connectionstring}";

// fromConnectionString must specify a transport constructor, coming from any transport package.
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol);

var connectCallback = function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
  } else {

    console.log('Client connected');
    client.on('message', function (msg) {

        // When using MQTT the following line is a no-op.
        client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
        console.log(msg.properties.propertyList[1].value);              
    });

    client.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function () {
      client.removeAllListeners();
      client.open(connectCallback);
    });
  }
};

client.open(connectCallback);

// Helper function to print results in the console
function printResultFor(op) {
  return function printResult(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
    if (res) console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
  };
}
```

**Test Results**
[image]

BTW, I have updated all of the azure-* libraries to latest version.

Comment: Hi, I am actually receiving the message on the web api, the "onMessage" function is being triggered. To clarify if i wasn't: the raspberry is receiving the message sent on line 6 but not the one sent in the "onMessage" function

Comment: Is `'../azure/sendingClient'` self-written? Could you please provide the code about this library?

Comment: I've edited my post with the code on the raspberry and the sending client

Comment: Could you please complete the `response` function?

Comment: Please add `client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));` in Receiver.js. When completing a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message has been processed. Please see the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js).

Comment: I've added it but it is not being called at the second message sent in the onMessage of the web api because it never reaches the raspberry.
Basically, it seems impossible to send a message in the receiver of the WebApi

Comment: In my scenario, i can not response the message in Receiver to trigger the `onMessage` in WebApi. Could please provide the code of `response` method?

Comment: The response method is not the issue, it can just be a console.log(msg),
I've added the sender on the raspberry pi.

Comment: How or when the onMessage in WebApi would be triggered?

Comment: Whenever any device sends a "device to cloud" message

Comment: @JeffAknine, I have tested this issue but can not reproduce. Please check the code in my update, even though there are some differences with yours, they are almost the same. I used a .net console app as a device to send d2c message to trigger the onMessage on WebApi.

Comment: @JeffAknine, have you checked that if the raspberry lost connection after received the message at first time?

Comment: The raspberry still has the connection because i can send multiple messages from another test application and the raspberry will receive them all

Comment: Have you used  a network protocol analyzer(such as wireshark) to analysis the messages?